# Effective Matrix-Vector multiplication in cuSparse

Tags: java, cuda, sparse-matrix, matrix-multiplication

I use  jCUSPARSE (cuSparse library wrapper) to make matrix-vector multiplication and I have a problem with function

```
cusparseDcsrmv(handle, cusparseOperation.CUSPARSE_OPERATION_NON_TRANSPOSE, matrixSize, matrixSize, alpha, descra, d_csrValA, d_rowPtrA, d_colIndA, x, beta, y);
```

If I use for descriptor initialization

```
cusparseSetMatType(descra, cusparseMatrixType.CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
```

it works  in 5-10 times faster then I use

```
cusparseSetMatType(descra, cusparseMatrixType.CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_SYMMETRIC);
```

I've tested it on a little symmetric matrix 5x5 and GENERAL works in 4 times faster then symmetric

I've tested it on a symmetric matrix 10000x10000 and GENERAL works in 10 times faster then symmetric

Comment: The matrices are both symmetric and square?

Comment: I have the same problem with the complex counterparts (CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_HERMITIAN).

Answer (score 1):

It appears the OP took this question down a side channel and [got an official answer from *njuffa*](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=214657):

> I checked with the CUDA library team, and they supplied the following
>   explanation:
>
> 1. For the nonsymmetric sparse matrix-vector multiplication the operation `y = A*x` is performed (`A` is stored explicitly).
> 2. For the symmetric matrix only its lower (or upper) triangular part of the matrix A is stored. We can write `y = A*x = (L+D)*x + L^{T}*x`,
>      where`A = (L+D) + L^{T}` with `L` being strictly lower triangular part of
>      the matrix and D being the diagonal. Since only `L+D` is stored, we need
>      to perform an operation with the matrix transpose `(L^{T})` to compute
>      the resulting vector `y`. This operation uses atomics because matrix
>      rows need to be interpreted as columns, and as multiple threads are
>      traversing them, different threads might add values to the same memory
>      location in the resulting vector `y`. This is the reason why the
>      matrix-vector multiplication with the matrix transpose and symmetric
>      matrix is slower than with the nonsymmetric matrix.
>
> The best way to speed up the computation (unless you are limited by
>   memory) would be to transform the symmetric into the nonsymmetric
>   matrix and call the appropriate `CUSPARSE` routine on it

In short: it's bottlenecking on shared memory. Not surprising, but interesting. :)

Comment: Pity. In my problem I can't really afford transforming to nonsymmetric because memory is a major limitation. I suppose I'll have to live with the slower calculation then! Or would there be another possibility that does not cost too much memory?

Comment: @leftaroundabout Intuitively, optimizing the matrix for only the parts that are being used would be ideal. Unfortunately, I don't know how to do this with the current API short of slipstreaming in a few low-level extensions, which are a bit over my head. I'll need to leave this to someone a bit cleverer and cognizant with CUDA internals than I, sorry!